# Set view property (setText & setOnClickListener) on Fragment's onViewCreated not working when using kotlin synthetic

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, synthetic

The TextView wont display the text while the value is existed. This operation is called within onViewCreated inside fragment. In the same case, the OnClickListener is also not working.
I have searched for the similar issue but have not found the exact same case. Did I miss something? Thank you for any help.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_login.*
---

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                      savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val isLogin = activity?.let { PrefHelper.getBoolean(it, PrefHelper.IS_LOGIN, false) }
    if (isLogin != null && isLogin) {
        onSignedIn()
    } else {
        onSignedOut()
    }
}

private fun onSignedIn() {
    form_login.visibility = View.GONE
    user_profile.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    var sEmail = ""
    var sFullName = ""
    var sPhone = ""
    if (activity != null) {
        PrefHelper.putBoolean(activity!!, PrefHelper.IS_LOGIN, true)
        sEmail = PrefHelper.getString(activity!!, PrefHelper.USER_EMAIL, "")
        sFullName = PrefHelper.getString(activity!!, PrefHelper.USER_FULL_NAME, "")
        val sPhonePrefix = PrefHelper.getString(activity!!, PrefHelper.USER_PHONE_PREFIX, "")
        val sPhoneSuffix = PrefHelper.getString(activity!!, PrefHelper.USER_PHONE_SUFFIX, "")
        sPhone = "$sPhonePrefix $sPhoneSuffix"
    }

    user_email.text = sEmail
    user_full_name.text = sFullName
    user_phone.text = sPhone

    logout.setOnClickListener { onSignedOut() }
}
```

[the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pxkM.jpg)

[breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqeqT.png)

Comment: Why there is two time `onCreateView(0` in your fragmnet

Comment: Oh sorry this seems to be my mistake when sending the post. I'll edit the post thanks

Comment: I'm using this fragment inside FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The onSignedIn() method is working as expected on the first time call. It also still appear after move to previous 3 fragments(viewpager). But after Activity onDestroy, this problem occurs. I have never found this issue when using Java. Is this the Kotlin issue?